# How to write a program that receives an ASCII code and display its character?

Tags: java, ascii

I'm new with Java and just learning... but how would you write a program that receives an ASCII code and displays its character. For example, if the user enters 97,the program displays character a.

Comment: Take a look at http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29 for reading the ASCII.  Then try to figure out how to convert the integer to a char (it's easier than you think).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int i = 97;
char c = (char)i; //c will contain 'a'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Integer.parseInt(string)` to turn that 97 into an integer. You can then explicitly cast that into a char:

```
String asciiCode = "97";
(char)Integer.parseInt(asciiCode);
```